# Stringtify object failed to store in mysql as JSON

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate

I trying to stringify list of string and store it in mysql in `JSON` format using hibernate:

```
List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
String first = "What is your name?";
options.add(first);

String option = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(options);
// option value is: ["what is your name?"]
```

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE question(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  label VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  question_type VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  mandatory TINYINT DEFAULT 0,
  editable TINYINT DEFAULT 0,
  `option` JSON NULL
);
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2209760405736391727L;

    private int id;

    private String label;

    private QuestionType questionType;

    private boolean mandatory;

    private boolean editable;

    private String options;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "label")
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Column(name = "question_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public QuestionType getQuestionType() {
        return questionType;
    }

    public void setQuestionType(QuestionType questionType) {
        this.questionType = questionType;
    }

    @Column(name = "mandatory")
    public boolean isMandatory() {
        return mandatory;
    }

    public void setMandatory(boolean mandatory) {
        this.mandatory = mandatory;
    }

    @Column(name = "editable")
    public boolean isEditable() {
        return editable;
    }

    public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
        this.editable = editable;
    }

    @Column(name = "option")
    public String getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(String options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
}
```

But it failed to persist into mysql:

Error: `could not execute statement`

Detailed error: `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option, question_type) values (0, 'label 1', 1, '["what is your name?"]', 'SINGL' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)`

I tried to search around the Internet but not able to get any hints.

Comment: please share complete code like code for your entity and code where you are trying to save the object using hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just with the name of your `option` column, because it is a keyword in mysql. You quoted it in your ddl statement, but when hibernate generates a query it doesn't quote names per default.
You can change this by setting (this will quote all db identifiers):

```
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

Or you can change column mapping:

```
@Column(name="\"option\"")
```

Or just don't use the keywords as names in your db schema.

Comment: Ah! Didn't realize that simple mistake, it works, thank you for the help.